# Dynamic column selection using Query in Google Sheets

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, flatten, google-query-language, sumproduct

I have a spreadsheet that is intended to tally up hours worked by location and generate amounts to invoice. I've figured out a (fairly brittle) way to achieve this using `SUMPRODUCT` on a sorted list of resources. However, this clearly doesn't scale.

[image: data that needs filtering, multiplying and summing]

It occurred to me that I could use a `QUERY` function along with `SUMPRODUCT` and free myself from the need to force an artificial structure onto the data set. However, since this formula needs to be copied across each column in my spreadsheet and since the column selector is part of the `SELECT` statement string it doesn't dynamically adjust as I copy the formula across each cell in the row. I tried building a formula using `COLUMN()` to dynamically build the `SELECT` statement but kept getting parse errors.

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EK2UcgsBqzb3Pfky8SALlTSEdeYvviv3QeyEPDu2mF0/edit?usp=sharing

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Put your image inside ![image description][image link] instead of an actual link, you just need to add an exclamation mark before the link to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(C3:K10="",,B3:B10&"×"&C3:K10*L3:L10&"×"&C2:K2)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1
  pivot Col3"),
 "offset 1", ))
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to understand the formula but I'm getting a bit lost in the nested functions. Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: @MarceloGuerra sure, IF range C3:K10 is empty do nothing otherwise multiply the range with L column and append B column and the row with dates via unique character ×. we get multidimensional array so we FLATTEN it all into one single column and SPLIT it into 3 columns on each unique character ×. then we use QUERY to sum values group it by B column and pivot it by row with dates. then we use 2nd QUERY to remove header row of inner QUERY. and coz we process arrays we use INDEX (just because its shorter than using ARRAYFORMULA)